# my htaccess file doesn't work to load css

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

i tried to find some answers but it doesnt work for me so i decided to ask here:
im new to codeigniter, after watching some few tutorials i end up with this .htaccess code.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /myprojectname
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|robots.txt)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

im using xampp on localhost, my problem is that i cant load my css in my view

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/metro-bootstrap.css">
```

when in fact i include css in `RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|robots.txt)`
 root looks like this

```
/
-application
-css
-js
-font
-system
-.htaccess
-index.php
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should already make sure that existing files are not rewritten. Try removing the line where you exclude the index.php, css and robots.txt.

Comment: The `RewriteCond $1` line needs to be removed.

Comment: In fact, that `RewriteCond` makes no sense at all …

Comment: true, remove `RewriteCond $1`

Comment: https://helponnet.com/2021/03/30/img-js-css-and-other-files-failed-to-load-after-using-rewriterule-in-htaccess/amp/

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to include css and robots.txt in that line because `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` takes care of it (basically it says Rewrite if it is NOT a file - '!-f' part), actually you can delete `RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|robots.txt)`. If then your css still doesn't work, use `<?php echo base_url();?>css/metro-bootstrap.css` this line of code, `base_url()` indicates base path in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the base in the .htaccess

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /name of the path base
```