# Can't load css, js and image with htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

I have problems in using the .htaccess file. css, js and image can't load if i use .htaccess file.

this my structure simple web.
I have some files and folders in the root directory :

1 css folder (include style.css).

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

h1 {
    color:#F00;
}
```

1 index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Clean URL</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head> 
<body>
<?php include "bukafile.php"; ?>
</body>
</head>
```

1 bukafile.php file

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['page']){
case '' : if(!file_exists ("home.php"))
die ("File Not Found");
include "home.php";
break;
case 'artikel' : if(!file_exists ("artikel.php"))
die ("File Not Found");
include "artikel.php";
break;
default: break;
}
?>
```

1 home.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Clean URL</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artikel order by id_artikel");
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$judul2 = str_replace(" ","-",$r[judul]);
?>

<p><?php echo"Judul : $r[judul]"; ?></p>
<p><?php echo"<a href='artikel/$r[id_artikel]/$judul2'>detail artikel</a>"; ?></p>

<?php
}
?>
</body>
</head>
```

1 artikel.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <title>Clean URL</title> 
    </head> 
    <body>
<h1>Percobaan</h1>
<?php


$detail=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE id_artikel='$_GET[id]'");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($detail);

echo "<p>$r[judul]</p>";
echo "<p>$r[content]</p>";

?>
</body>
    </head>
```

1 .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^artikel/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=artikel&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

In this case, css file can't load in artikel php (tag h1) if the source code `<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` but if i change source code `<link href="../../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` it's running well.. so, how can I edit the file htacess without making changes to the source code css?? thank's for the answer

Comment: thank's for you're advice.. first time, i must to learn about PDO

Answer (score 3):

This is because you've changed your **relative URI base**. When the browser loads:

```
/index.php?page=something
```

The **base** is `/`. But when the browser loads:

```
/artikel/123/abcd
```

The **base** is `/artikel/123/`. That's what happens when you relative URLs. The browser has no idea that your files are actually somewhere else or that the URL will be rewritten. So you need to tell the browser what the base is.

Try adding this in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the base in the .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /name of the path base
```

read this post too [my htaccess file doesn't work to load css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654042/my-htaccess-file-doesnt-work-to-load-css/53136709#53136709)